# AmChart Background Grid

Tags: graph, amcharts, gridlines

I'm currently developing Amchart chart and its reading form local 
database. I want a way to make the background grid lines above the graphs with

```
fillAlphas= 1?
```

You can try using [this](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-with-changing-color/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [`gridAboveGraphs`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#gridAboveGraphs) to true in your chart config.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // other config omitted
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/944wn6n0/)

Comment: Thanks , Is there a way to make the grid little bit darker?
and for the horizontal  also?

Comment: Set the [valueAxis' `gridAlpha`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#gridAlpha) and [categoryAxis' `gridAlpha`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#gridAlpha) to a larger value. By default they're set to a small decimal value, so anything closer to or equal to 1 will make it darker. I highly recommend looking through the documentation as it is very thorough.